# ReferenceError: "rTrim()" when snding values to inputs with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following form:

```
<h:form id="formprueba">

  <!-- Panel -->
  <div class="panel panel-info" style="margin-top:1%; margin-left:2%; margin-right:2%;">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p:panel id="panel" widgetVar="panelwv" header="#{msg.Sgc005tit}" toggleable="true" collapsed="false" style="margin-top:1%; margin-left:1%; margin-right:1%;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <p:inputText id="codigo" style="margin-bottom:3px; margin-top:3px; width:200px; height:45px;" maxlength="50" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bd.getMessage('htmlvalidate')}" value="#{prueba.codigo}" />
            <p:watermark for="codigo" value="#{msg.sgc001cod}" />
            <p:spacer height="1" />
            <p:message for="codigo" />
            <p:inputText id="desc" style="margin-bottom:3px; margin-top:3px; width:200px; height:45px;" maxlength="100" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bd.getMessage('htmlvalidate')}" value="#{prueba.desc}" />
            <p:watermark for="desc" value="#{msg.sgc001des}" />
            <p:spacer height="1" />
            <p:message for="desc" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <h:inputText id="vop" value="#{prueba.validarOperacion}" />
      </p:panel>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Main content -->
  <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">

        <div class="box">
          <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">Data Table With Full Features</h3>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-header -->
          <div class="box-body">
            <table id="tbResult" class="table table-bordered table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th width="5%">
                    <center>
                      <p:commandLink onclick="fm_check('toDelete',true)"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x" title="#{msg.borrar}"></i>
                      </p:commandLink>
                    </center>
                  </th>
                  <th>#{msg.Sgc001tbcod}</th>
                  <th>#{msg.Sgc001tbdes}</th>
                  <th width="10%">
                    <center>#{msg.bvt001TbEnviar}</center>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="#{prueba.table}" varStatus="loop">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="5%">
                      <center>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="toDelete" class="chk" value="#{prueba.vltabla[loop.index][0]}" />
                      </center>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <h:outputText value="#{prueba.vltabla[loop.index][0]}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <h:outputText value="#{prueba.vltabla[loop.index][1]}" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="10%">
                      <center><i title="Enviar" onclick="enviar('#{prueba.vltabla[loop.index][0]}','#{prueba.vltabla[loop.index][1]}','1');" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x text-info" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
                      </center>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </c:forEach>
              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th width="5%">
                    <center>
                      <p:commandLink onclick="fm_check('toDelete',true)"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x" title="#{msg.borrar}"></i>
                      </p:commandLink>
                    </center>
                  </th>
                  <th>#{msg.Sgc001tbcod}</th>
                  <th>#{msg.Sgc001tbdes}</th>
                  <th width="10%">
                    <center>#{msg.bvt001TbEnviar}</center>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
            </table>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </section>

</h:form>
```

and this JS:

```
    function enviar(vT0,vT1,vT2){
        alert("Llamo al metodo");
        alert("codigo: " + vT0);
        alert("desc: " + vT1);
        alert("vop: " + vT2);
          document.getElementById("formprueba:codigo").value = rTrim(vT0);
          document.getElementById("formprueba:desc").value = rTrim(vT1);
          document.getElementById("formprueba:vop").value = rTrim(vT2);
          //updateInput('formprueba:codigo', '#F2F2F2');
          alert("final de la operacion");
        }
```

The alerts print the desired values that I want to send to their respective inputs, but the values are not sent. What am I doing wrong here?

When clicking the image at the column **editar** it should send the values to their respective inputs. What am i missing?

I just updated the JS and it doesnt print the las alert... i asume there's something wrong when it reaches the first document.getElementById("formprueba:codigo").value = rTrim(vT0);

I ask for some guidance please.

Comment: any console messages that may shed light on this? There's no inputs in your markup, and certainly nothing with those id's you're looking for

Comment: no msg on console, there are no errors... the thing is that when i call the js enviar(value1, value2, value3); it should send the selected values from a method in java into the input's that are inside the panel... but it does not send them... but its reading the correct value's since each alert show's the values that is being read.

Comment: the only thing that apear's in console is this msg:

ADVERTENCIA: JSF1091: no se ha encontrado ningún tipo MIME para el archivo fa/fontawesome-webfont.woff2.  Para resolverlo, agregue una asignación de tipo MIME al archivo web.xml de la aplicación.


but i dont think that has anything to do with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is difficult to test, but I can see that you're putting the name of the form when selecting the inputs by id. So, instead of

```
document.getElementById("formprueba:codigo").value = rTrim(vT0);
document.getElementById("formprueba:desc").value = rTrim(vT1);
document.getElementById("formprueba:vop").value = rTrim(vT2);
```

you can try

```
document.getElementById("codigo").value = rTrim(vT0);
document.getElementById("desc").value = rTrim(vT1);
document.getElementById("vop").value = rTrim(vT2);
```

Comment: I think i tried that already... but let me give it another go and will update you on that one.

Comment: Yes i tried that that matheusr and still not working

Comment: It's strange, it is probably something else then. See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jxkk1vCkqe2w0o5k0BtI?p=preview), it is similar to your case and works as expected. Is the function **enviar** executed until the end? Can you **console.log** at the end and check if it prints?

Comment: i just added an alert at the end of the js to see if it complete's the entire operation but it does not... ill update post so it's more clear

Comment: How does the rTrim looks like?

Comment: So it turns out that the entire problem was rTrim(); in developers console i noticed that breaked there and gave some error of ReferenceError: "rTrim()" is not defined. so i removed it and work's like a charme... thanks matheusr for all the help...